# Rails 3 - KendoUI - Trouble accessing JSON object - Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, kendo-ui

I've created a simple Rails 3 JSON api with a 'user' model and 'users' controller.  The api itself is working fine, however...

I'm attempting to use the Kendo UI datasource to populate the grid and I'm running into an issue.

Using the Chrome network tool I can see that the JSON data is coming back from the server:

```
[{"user":{"created_at":"2012-02-08T17:33:27Z","first_name":"Angelina","id":1,"last_name":"Jolie","password":"","updated_at":"2012-02-08T17:33:27Z","user_name":""}},{"user":{"created_at":"2012-02-08T17:34:50Z","first_name":"Milla","id":2,"last_name":"Jovovich","password":"","updated_at":"2012-02-08T17:34:50Z","user_name":""}}]
```

Here is the Javascript that is used to create the grid and the datasource:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var sharableDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/users",
                dataType: "json"

            }
        }           
    });


    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: sharableDataSource,
            columns: [
            { 
                title: "First Name",
                field:"first_name"
            },

            {   
                title: "Last Name",
                field: "last_name"              
            }]
    });        

});
```

The grid definition appears to be working, because when the grid renders it is displaying the 'Title' that I specified in the grid:

[image]

But... as you can see, no data appears.  **And I am getting an Uncaught ReferenceError for the 'first_name' field**:

[image]

Any thoughts on what may be causing this?

Comment: I think you need to edit this setting during your Rails Initialization process: `ActiveRecord.Base.include_root_in_json = false`

Comment: You sir are a genius.  I put that in the config/environment.rb file and now it works.  Don't know why, but it does.  If you can submit your comment as an answer I will mark it as the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to edit this setting during your Rails Initialization process:

`ActiveRecord.Base.include_root_in_json = false`

**Update:** Glad it helped... :) This is because by default Rails renders it's JSON response with the root element included. Most of the JS Libraries and Frameworks like Kendo, Backbone etc don't like that..